# Asynchronous server shuts down immediately after creating boost::asio

Tags: c++, boost, asio

The server starts and accepts connections, all clients, even if more than 10 are connected, send a message but there is no response.
The read and write function uses the index of the received client's account and works with it. Therefore, there is an additional parameter in the headers.
We accept the connection and pass its number to the header and there with the socket of this number we are working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <clocale>
#include <vector>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace std;

class tcp_server
{
private:
    io_service service;
    int port;
    enum { buff_size = 1024 };
    ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint;
    ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor;
    int countClients = 0;
    int accept_i = 0;
    struct client
    {
        ip::tcp::socket sock;
        char buff[buff_size] = { };
    };
    vector<client> clients;
public:
    tcp_server(io_service& service, int port) : service(), acceptor(service), endpoint(ip::tcp::v4(), port)
    {
        this->port;
        acceptor.open(endpoint.protocol());
        acceptor.set_option(ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
        acceptor.bind(endpoint);
        acceptor.listen();
        clients.reserve(10);
    }
    void start()
    {
        start_service_in_thread();
    }
    void start_service_in_thread()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            boost::thread(service_func_for_thread);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            boost::thread(acceptor_func_for_thread);
            accept_i++;
        }
    }
    void service_func_for_thread()
    {
        service.run();
    }
    void accept_handler(const boost::system::error_code& error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            countClients++;
            do_read_this(countClients - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Acceptor error\n";
            cout << error.message() << endl;
        }
    }
    void acceptor_func_for_thread()
    {
        acceptor.async_accept(
            clients[accept_i].sock,
            boost::bind(&tcp_server::accept_handler, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error)
        );
    }
    void do_read_this(int thisClientIndex)
    {
        clients[thisClientIndex].sock.async_read_some(
            buffer(clients[thisClientIndex].buff),
            boost::bind(&tcp_server::read_handler,
                this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,
                thisClientIndex)
        );
    }
    void read_handler(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred, int thisClientIndex)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            clients[thisClientIndex].sock.async_write_some(
                buffer(clients[thisClientIndex].buff),
                boost::bind(&tcp_server::write_handler,
                    this,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,
                    thisClientIndex)
            );
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Error reading from socket\n";
            cout << error.message() << endl;
        }
    }
    void write_handler(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred, int thisClientIndex)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            do_read_this(thisClientIndex);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Error write in socket\n";
            cout << error.message() << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    try
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
        io_service service;
        tcp_server* server = new tcp_server{ service, 5000 };
        server->start();
        service.run();
    }
    catch (exception& ex)
    {
        cout << "Exception: " << ex.what();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The client connects to the server and when it sends a connection, no response is received.
Please help.

Comment: One big undefined behaviour. `clients`  vector has size 0. `reserve` != `resize`. Try resize you will see compilation errors, because there is no `tcp::socket` constructor which takes no parameters, it must get at least `io_service/io_context` as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

1. `service.run();` in `main` has nothing to do so it returns immediately so `main` returns causing program to end.
2. Creating background threads is not necessary here.
3. You are (again) creating a temporary objects `boost::thread` that immediately go out of scope. And unless `BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_THREAD_DESTRUCTOR_CALLS_TERMINATE_IF_JOINABLE` is specified you will end up with a bunch of detached threads.

Answer (score 0):

When the `io_service::run()` method has no work to do, it returns.

You should either

1. `post()` at least one task to the `io_service` before calling `run()`,
2. or "lock" it with `io_service::work`

   ```
   io_service service;
   boost::asio::io_service::work work(service);
   ```

The latter requires a call to `service.stop()` to cause `run()` to exit, otherwise it will run eternally.

Note however: you don't really need two `io_service`s or any threads in an async application.